# [__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hii I am new in ios developer.I want to delete row in tableview.i will implement the code but when i slide the tableview than click delete button than display error

[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

here is my screenshot

[image]

here is my code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [cart_data count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cellitem";

    cell *cells = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cells == nil) {
        cells = [[cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    cells.lbl_title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cart_data[indexPath.row][@"name"]];
    cells.lbl_price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cart_data[indexPath.row][@"price"]];
    cells.lbl_qty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cart_data[indexPath.row][@"qty"]];


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cart_data[indexPath.row][@"img_url"]]];

    [cells.image setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] ];
    return cells;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


        [cart_data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.table reloadData];
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }
}
```

help me any solution...thanks for advance

Comment: I guess that `cart_data` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: cart data is nsmutablearray.bcs they data come in to server

Comment: cart_data Should be Declared With NSMutableArray and check  if(cart_data.count > indexpath.row) -> THE PERFORM  DELTEE

Comment: @MikeAlter ok i will try

Comment: @MikeAlter same problem

Comment: Guess explanation: When do you do `[cart_data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, before that, do NSLog(@"cart_data class: %@",[cart_data class]);. I think that's a NSArray, I suspect a JSON and a "assign" from the JSON value to `cart_data`. But if the JSON parsed is not mutable...

Comment: PRINT THAT  SEE NSLog(@"array's class: %@", NSStringFromClass([cart_data class]));

Comment: @Larme@mike Alter ok

Comment: @dany your array is type of nsarray not nsmutablearray i think either you assign array directly to cart_data that's why this issue happen

Comment: cart data is nsmutablearray

Comment: NSLog(@"array responds to addObject: %@", 
          [cart_data respondsToSelector: @selector(addObject:)] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

Comment: pls check that true or false in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: No __NSCFArray means you have to remove object from nsarray not nsmutable array. can you put assignment code here?

Comment: 2016-06-04 14:31:25.718 deletecell[35748:60b] array responds to addObject: YES
2016-06-04 14:31:25.721 deletecell[35748:60b] array's class: __NSCFArray

Comment: cart_data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: what you assign in cart_data object i need that line? any way i think you need to do like this
cart_data=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anyArray>

Comment: @dany your data came from service so your data is not mutable data.

Comment: cart_data= [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:yourServiceArray] mutableCopy]; try this way data add in array may be works that. @dany

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya ok i will try

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya `..MutableArray ... initWithArray` and `mutableCopy` is redundant. One of them is sufficient.

Comment: cart_data should be NSMutableArray  in place of NSArray . If you want to remove object.

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly says that `cart_data` is `NSArray` rather than the expected `NSMutableArray`.

Even if the declaration (and initialization) is correct it could happen that later an immutable array is assigned to that property which makes it immutable. In this case you need to call `mutableCopy` on the `NSArray` instance.

PS: You can simplify the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` line

```
...deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation...
```